# pivot table with if else condition pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, machine-learning

i have a table :

| project | location | category | lifecycle | ftecount>3 | bpssscore |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | Bangalore | s | Incre | 41 | 3.98 |
| Sys | Bangalore | s | SDS | 35.3 | 3.98 |
| Syst | Chennai | Task | 13 | 2 | 3.98 |
| EPS | Bangalore | s | Task | 5 | 3.98 |
| foss | Bangalore | s | sds | 6 | 3.98 |
| opc | Noida | task | 13 | 1 | 3.98 |

want output as:

| project | loc_Bangalore | loc_Chennai | loc_Noida | cat_s | cat_task | ftecount>3 | bpssscore>3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| Sys | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| Syst | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| EPS | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| foss | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| opc | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 |

here condition are:

1.want to add new columns dynamically from unique values of column location,category.

2.in new columns value will be according to below condition :
--if location = 'Banglore' then put 1 else 0 in new column loc_banglore.

similar condition is for all location unique value and category(on which new column is added in df)

3.for ftecount and bpss column we have to check only condition:
-- if ftecount>3 then 1 else 0

same logic for bpss column.'

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `pd.get_dummies()` to achieve the one-hot encoding results, and `lambda()` function to filter if score is > 3 or not.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'project': ['abc', 'Sys', 'Syst' ,'EPS', 'foss', 'opc'], 
    'location': ['Bangalore' ,'Bangalore', 'Chennai', 'Bangalore', 'Bangalore', 'Noida'],
    'category': ['s', 's', 'task', 's', 's', 'task'], 
    'ftecount': [41, 35.3, 2, 5, 6, 1],
    'bpssscore': [3.98, 3.98, 3.98, 3.98, 3.98, 3.98]
})
df['ftecount>3'] = df['ftecount'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x>3 else 0)
df['bpssscore>3'] = df['bpssscore'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x>3 else 0)

df = pd.concat([df['project'], 
                pd.get_dummies(df['location'], prefix='loc'), 
                pd.get_dummies(df['category'], prefix='cat'), 
                df['ftecount>3'], 
                df['bpssscore>3']
               ], axis=1)
```

Output df

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Firstly replace the uppercase T to lowercase in category column:

```
df['category']=df['category'].str.replace('T','t')
```

Now make use of `pd.get_dummies()`, `drop()` and `reset_index()` method:

```
out=pd.get_dummies(df.set_index('project').drop(['ftecount>3','bpssscore','lifecycle'],1)).reset_index()
```

Finally use `gt()` and `astype()` method:

```
out['ftecount>3']=df['ftecount>3'].gt(3).astype(int)
out['bpssscore']=df['bpssscore'].gt(3).astype(int)
```

Now If you print `out` you will get:

[image]